# Show $|Ax|≤M|x|$ if $M=n*\max\{|a_{ij}|: i,j=1,\dots,n\}.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$ and let $A=\{a_{ij}\}$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Also, let $|\cdot|$ denote the Euclidean $n$-norm. I want to show that $|Ax|≤M|x|$ if $M=n\cdot\max\{|a_{ij}|: i,j=1,\dots,n\}.$ I have written this all out and can only get $|Ax|≤M(x_1+\cdots+x_n).$ 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has

$$|Ax|=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{l=1}^na_{kl}x_l\right)^2}$$

Let’s have a look at the inner bracket using Cauchy-Schwartz

$$\left(\sum_{l=1}^na_{kl}x_l\right)^2\leq\sum_{l=1}^na_{kl}^2\sum_{l=1}^nx_l^2$$

We therefore have

$$\left(\sum_{l=1}^na_{kl}x_l\right)^2\leq nM^2|x|^2$$

This leads to

$$|Ax|\leq\sqrt{n\cdot nM^2|x|^2}=nM|x|$$

Comment: This is very clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$|A(x)|^2=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\sum_{j=1}^{j=n} a_{ij}^2x_j^2$

$\sum_{j=1}^{j=n} a_{ij}^2x_j^2\leq nmax(|a_{ij}^2|(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)$ since $|a_{ij}|\leq max(|a_{ij})$. This implies that

$|A(x)|^2=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\sum_{j=1}^{j=n} a_{ij}^2x_j^2\leq\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}nmax(|a_{ij}^2)|x|^2\leq M^2|x|^2$